# Can I use operator== for pointers?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I created some Object with overloaded operator== in it.

```
    class Corridor
    {
    public:
       Corridor(int iStart, int iEnd);
        ~Corridor();

        // Overloaded operators to simplify search in container.
        friend bool operator==(const Corridor& lhs, const int rhs);
        friend bool operator==(const int lhs, const Corridor& rhs);

    protected:
        int m_iIntersectionIDStart;
        int m_iIntersectionIDEnd;
    };
```

In this case, if I create somewhere vector of Corridors:

```
    vector<Corridor> m_vCorridors;
```

proggram works fine and I'm able to use find algorithm:

```
    auto itCorridor = find(m_vCorridors.begin(), m_vCorridors.end(), someID);
```

BUT in case if I create vector of pointers:

```
    vector<Corridor*> m_vCorridors;
```

I receive an errors:
Error   1   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const int' to 'Corridor *'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    41
Error   2   error C2040: '==' : 'Corridor *' differs in levels of indirection from 'const int'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    41

Tried to overload operator== in different ways, but it doesn't work for this case. Does somebody knows what I should do to resolve issue?

Comment: Warning: If your implementation of `operator==` tests `if (intValue >= m_iIntersectionIDStart && intValue <= m_iIntersectionIDEnd)`, your equality operator does not satisfy the transitive relation: it's possible to have `int` values `a` and `c` and a `Corridor` instance `b` such that `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`.  I'd recommend instead defining a member function, e.g. `Contains(int)` to test that relation instead to avoid possible bugs and confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `find` is attempting to compare a pointer to a `Corridor` to an `int`. To compare the `Corridor` to the `int` again, you would need to define your own comparator, using [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Assuming you can use C++11 lambdas,

```
find_if(m_vCorridors.begin(), m_vCorridors.end(), [=](Corridor* cp) {
    return *cp == someID;
});
```

Comment: It works, but how can I change `someID` during programme run? If I use comparator with two parameters, and `bind2nd` in my `find_if` call, should it work?

Comment: You don't need to pass it in as a second parameter. You can use local variables inside lambdas, so as long as `someID` is in scope, you're good to go. See this article on lambdas to learn more about capturing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx